# Divide excel file in smaller files of 5000 lines each without degrouping the lines

Tags: excel, vba, divide

I need to divide an excel sheet with 60000+ lines into different files with around 5000 lines each. The data inserted is grouped and I need the new tables not to split these groups, but I can't manage to do it, nor to create a new file each time.

I tried with the following code but I can't manage to make it run properly:

```vb
Public Sub split()
Dim sheetnumber, t As Double
line = 0
k = lastrow 'this gives the last full row in the file

sheetnumber = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(k / 5000, 1)

For i = 1 To sheetnumber Step 1

line = line + 5000

article = CStr(Sheets("sheet1").Cells(linea, 1).Value)
For m = 0 To 30 Step 1
    If article = CStr(Sheets("sheet1").Cells(linea + m, 1).Value) Then
    GoTo e
    Else
    line = line + m
    Exit For
    End If
e:

Next m
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
For n = 1 To line Step 1
   ActiveSheet.Row(n) = Sheets("sheet1").Row(n) ' i also tried to put a cycle here to 
'copy the whole row and then go to the next one but the rest won't work
Next n

ActiveSheet.Select
ActiveSheet.Move


Next i

End Sub
```

The file is composed like so:

4999. article 0
5000. article 1
5001. article 1
5002. article 1
5003. article 2
5004. article 2
5005. article 3

...

9999. article 56
10000. article 57
10001. article 57
10002. article 57
10003. article 57
10004. article 58

I need the new files to include the whole rows from 5002 to 1, and another file to include all the rows from 10003 to 5002 and so on to the end of the file (last row is around 60000), without breaking the article group.

Tthank you for any suggestion/help to do this

Comment: The thing is... I still don't get your patern to divide the files. Do you really want fixed number rows?

Comment: So you want to copy the first 5002 rows, and then the next 5002 rows and then the next 5002 rows, and so on?  And each group would need to be in a different workbook?

Comment: No, i wrote the line number as an example. i want the code to copy in the new file 5000 lines, but if doing so is going to split an article, i want it to continue copying until the article finish, and than start a new file. in this way i can have a little more than 5000 lines, but not splitted articles. i.e. using the list i provided, i will have a file that goes from line 1-5002, another file 5003-10003. if there were 2 more lines with Article 57, it would have been 5003-10005.

Comment: So then, you want to copy to a new file all rows relative to Article 1, and to a second new file all rows relative to article 2, and so on?

Comment: No, sorry if i can't explain myself well :) i need a bunch of files of around 5000 rows, without breaking the single articles continuity. each article can have 3 to more than 20 rows, i just don't want to split an article in half, but i want it grouped with the rest of his lines if an article is in middle of 5000 or 10000 or 15000....up to 60000+

Comment: Ok, sou you want to copy in groups of 5000 rows by default **but** if row 5000 of data is, let's say, `Article 123`, you want to make sure **all rows** from `Article 123` are in that file, even if that means to copy more than 5000 rows, to avoid splitting `Articles` So some files could have 5012, others 5020, others 5008, and so on. It's not exactly 5000 rows (it could be, but it would be a coincidence). Is that right?

Comment: yes, correct. thanks